# Group by Field in Matrix Field

Tags: entries, matrix, group

Is it possible to group by a field within a matrix field.
I have a channel of players which holds their details.
I have a structure for teams which includes a matrix field for a Player.

The Player matrix has 2 fields:

1 - Position (Drop down with: Goalkeeper, Defender, Midfielder)

2 - Entries field linked to Players Channel.

When accessing the matrix is it possible to Group the blocks by the Position field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Craft's handy [`group`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter.

```
{% set players = entry.myPlayersMatrix %}
{% set playersGrouped = players|group('myPositionDropdown.label') %}

{% for position, playersInPosition in playersGrouped %}
    <h2>{{ position }}</h2>
    <ul>
    {% for player in playersInPosition %}
        {% set playerData = craft.entries.section('myPlayersChannel').relatedTo(player).first() %}
        <li>
            {{ playerData.fullName }}
            {{ playerData.age }}
            ...
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah - never realised it was possible with matrix fields as well. Straight forward then - thanks!