# group Matrix blocks and also order by Matrix field for a given block

Tags: matrix, group, blocks, order

I'm wondering if I might have a little too much inception madness in my thinking with this problem.

Enhancing a site we built for a conference last year. As there's an annual conference each year and some of the speakers are the same, we decided to reevaluate the approach.

What we have now is 2 channels, `Speaker` and `Conference`. Speaker contains all the speakers that could ever make an appearance at the conference and Conference contains the specific details about that conference.

Within conference, we have a Matrix field called `Talks` with a `workshop`, `general` and `special event` block.

I want to be able to group talk blocks by their block type, is that possible?

Going a step further, in the case of a `workshop` - that block has a `workshopRound` select field of 1, 2 or 3 - I'd love to be able to then group entries with those blocks by their round number.

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great chance to use the [group](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter.

First, get all your matrix blocks as an array:

```
{% set talkBlocks = entry.talks.find() %}
```

Then group them by type:

```
{% set talksByCategories = talkBlocks|group('type') %}
```

At this point, you have an associative array where the keys are the block types, and the values are arrays of the blocks with that type. So `talksByCategories.workshop` or `talksByCategories['workshop']` will be the workshops.

You can group the workshops by round:

```
{% set workshopsByRound = talksByCategories.workshop|group('workshopRound.value') %}
```

You should check that there were any workshops first (twig's [defined](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html) test):

```
{% if talksByCategories['workshop'] is defined %} ...
```

Comment: thank you Marion, this looks a lot more succinct than the path I was initially looking at going down with http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6732/solution-for-matrix-within-matrix-or-more-robust-table-fields mixed with http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/group-by-field-in-matrix-field 

The first part worked but the 2nd I was struggling with. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks again.